# Limiting effects, like with `Freer`, using MTL-style

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, free-monad

Motivation: To be able to control effects in MTL like we can in `Free`/`Freer`-style.

The example might be slightly contrived—imagine a program with some basic operations (GHC 8.2 using `freer-simple`),

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-10.2 --install-ghc runghc --package freer-simple
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
import Control.Monad.Freer

data Effect next where
  ReadFilename :: String -> Effect String
  WriteOutput :: Show a => a -> Effect ()
  Computation :: Int -> Int -> Effect Int

readFilename :: Member Effect effs => String -> Eff effs String
readFilename = send . ReadFilename

writeOutput :: (Member Effect effs, Show a) => a -> Eff effs ()
writeOutput = send . WriteOutput

computation :: Member Effect effs => Int -> Int -> Eff effs Int
computation i1 i2 = send $ Computation i1 i2
```

With this, we can model a program that does some simple operations, reading a file and outputting it, doing a computation and outputting it,

```
program :: Eff '[Effect, IO] ()
program = do
 contents <- readFilename "test.txt"
 writeOutput contents
 result <- computation 12 22
 writeOutput result
```

We can then implement our interpreters, which will be were we decide how to run the code. Our first interpreter will be placed client-side, and will run `IO` instructions locally, and it will send off the pure instructions to a server, for calculation,

```
runClientEffect :: Eff '[Effect, IO] a -> IO a
runClientEffect = runM . interpretM (\case
  ReadFilename filename -> readFile filename
  WriteOutput s -> print s
  Computation i1 i2 -> do
    print "Imagine the networking happening here"
    pure $ i1 + i2)
```

The server side we can skip for now.

What this hopefully demonstrates is an interface that relies on some aspects being pure, and thereby able to be sent to a server, while others are impure, and are run locally.

What I struggle with, is how to do this in an MTL-style, namely how to limit the amount of `IO` that can be done in the monad operations.

Let me know if the question is too vague!

Comment: You may find [this example of mtl style](https://github.com/lexi-lambda/mtl-style-example) informative.

Comment: Ah, I actually had that cloned down, but completely forgot about it! Thanks, will check it out (this time for sure) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's quite straightforward.

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
```

Instead of an `Effect` datatype representing the syntax of our DSL, we define an `EffectMonad` typeclass that abstracts the monad itself.

```
class Monad m => EffectMonad m where
  readFilename :: String -> m String
  writeOutput :: Show a => a -> m ()
  computation :: Int -> Int -> m Int
```

The program is the same (up to the type signature).

```
program :: EffectMonad m => m ()
program = do
  contents <- readFilename "test.txt"
  writeOutput contents
  result <- computation 12 22
  writeOutput result
```

And an interpreter is given as an instance (if you are layering effects with transformers, that's where we run into the `O(n*m)` instance problem).

```
instance EffectMonad IO where
  readFilename filename = readFile filename
  writeOutput s = print s
  computation i1 i2 = do
    print "Imagine the networking happening here"
    pure $ i1 + i2
```

Then running the program is just instantiating it with the right type.

```
main :: IO ()
main = program
```

Comment: Huh, that's quite straightforward! :) I don't know why I was trying to be all fancy and define my own monad transformers and stuff :/ Thanks!